# How to know when a 360 rotation was performed around any given axis?

Tags: rotations, angle

If I have any given axis, e.g. $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left[ \begin{array}{ccc} 0 & -1 & 1 \end{array} \right]$ and a rotational speed of $\omega = 1.5$ [deg/s] around that axis. How can I check that I performed a full 360 rotation around the axis using only the angle measurements?

I know I can use a velocity formula $\omega = \frac{\theta}{\delta_t}$ but in this case I need to check the rotation using the angle.

Comment: couldn't you just check whethre any point not on the axis is "back home"?

Comment: Your question is unclear. How to find if a rotation angle is 360 given the rotation angle? This is either trivial or something is not explained.

Comment: Why not just do 360/1.5? In other words - every 4 minutes.